# wrong date format in bi reports oracle

Tags: oracle, rtf, xml-publisher

I have the following date which is in varchar2(11) column in database:

```
 select  valid_untill from SALES_ORDERS_V where header_id = 7999410;
```

> 30-May-2016

Using rtf template and xml source, the report output (PDF) is:

> 4950-11-19 04:45:49:0

I don't know its equal to "30-May-2016".

Why this is showing this, as I did not do any formating in rtf?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with either RTF or XML-Publisher, but whenever you retrieve a date saved in string format, IF you use it as a date in your code and not as a string, you must make sure you retrieve it correctly.

In this case, with your select statement: it shouldn't be `select valid-until from...` (or is it really misspelled, with two l at the end: valid_until?) If it is meant to be used as a date, it should be

```
select to_date(valid_until, 'dd-Mon-yyyy') from ...
```

Really the problem here is that the date is stored as a string and not in the date datatype. Good luck!

Comment: could not get the point, if it is stored as String then why we can not display it as String?

Comment: Clearly your code around it interprets it as a date, so it expects it as a date. Perhaps you have a variable declared as date datatype, to which you assign this string. Hard to know as you haven't really shared any of your code. But if a cast from string to date happens anywhere (in the query, in your code, or anywhere else), especially if it is an implicit cast because you pass a string but what the compiler expects is a date, you will have this problem. Try to see where this value is used in your code.

Comment: you can display it as a string, but if you want to do comparisons of dates, you must first convert the string to a DATE with to_date.  And if you want to change the format of a string representation, use to_date to change it to a DATE, then to_char to change it back to a string, in the desired format.  In any event, it is a design FAIL to have stored the date as a varchar in the first place.

Comment: To clarify: if you had a STRING variable everywhere, and you passed valid_until to it, it wouldn't display it as a different string, which looks like a date and a time component. There MUST be some attempt to cast to date, either in your query or the code that uses it or anyway, somewhere between the base table in the database and what you see in your PDF output. As I said I am not familiar with RTF template - do you have a variable in it which must be of date datatype, but it receives a string?

Comment: Or are you asking (as @mathguy suggests) why a string representation of a date in one format is coming out in your pdf in a different format representing a different date?

Comment: @mathguy There is no such variable, I think some implicit casting is occur. so why this is showing something like date.